# A tag with "1 watchers" in SO Teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams, plurals

Here are a tag with

> 1 **watchers** and 3 questions

[image]

Pluralization has always been sneaky in programs, right?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236746

Comment: You better upgrade your house's security and defenses.

Comment: I got a dog explicitly to be able to call out bugs like this. My pup is trained to recognize Jeff on sight and not let him close. She also gets more jumpy in the presence of giant letters of the alphabet.

Comment: "Here are a tag..." ha ha :/ As a workaround, you could watch the tag, or, if you are that lone watchers, persuade someone else to watch it too.

Comment: @Patrice If you plant a [Magnet-shroom](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Magnet-shroom) in your yard, the big S gets removed from Jeff and thus isn't effective anymore.

Comment: Is that a problems?

Comment: Using **watcher(s)** is a solution, the laziest one. _Answer(s), Vote(s), View(s)_ this way either it's 1 or many it doesn't matter.

Comment: I just need to point out: Here *are* a tag with.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala while technically true - I get very annoyed when I see this. It's not a difficult problem to solve.

Comment: look just post a thread on the English SE and get one of the mods to say this is technically grammatically acceptable

Comment: RE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236746 - and people wonder why StackOverflow has an ingrained culture of nastiness.

Comment: Nobody was watching the watchers.

Comment: Is this actually something people care about? Or are such bug reports more of the "I'm helping" mentality than of the "this bothers me and needs to be fixed"?

Comment: @lucidbrot A bug is a bug. "People don't care" isn't a valid reason not to report a bug.

Comment: @iBug yes, but "I don't care enough to make the effort to report" is a valid reason not to. I'm just surprised somebody apparently is bothered enough by this

Comment: This wouldn't be a problem if we could all speak Indonesian instead.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Chinese is also a solution where there's absolutely no noun plurals/gender/declension, verb conjugation/tenses, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. If you see any giant letterS flying your way, please redirect them at me.

This was a not-so-obvious fail in our build config, that we totally missed. As a consequence of an invalid connection string, the build boxes weren't able to reach the DB that contains the translations, so the English non-pluralized fallback was used (which *looked* fine in most cases).

[image: BEWARE THE GIANT S]

The build configuration has now been fixed, and all the strings should now be pluralized correctly.

Answer (score -5):

> Pluralization has always been sneaky in programs, right?

It is. It's just another code line of `if` where 90% of developers does not waste time to add. Maybe because they are too lazy (including me).

Few years back I found kind of a solution for this, *it's not the best but does the job*. I always add a **s** in bracket(s).

- Watcher(s)
- Answer(s)
- Question(s)
- Vote(s)
- View(s)

This way either it's 1 or many, it doesn't matter.

<sub>[(Based on my comment)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370299/a-tag-with-1-watchers-in-so-teams#comment605034_370299)</sub>

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311779/no-plural-forms-for-youve-earned-this-badge-n-times/311987#comment1019274_311779